# Is there anything special about Gamma distribution with the shape parameter k=e?

Tags: simulation, fitting, negative-binomial-distribution, gamma-distribution

Is there any unique property of $\mathrm{Gamma}(k=e, \text{ scale})$ or a Negative binomial distribution with $r=e$? Here, $e$ is Euler's number, $e \approx 2.71828$.

The reason I'm asking is that one of the variables in my computer simulations can be fitted by $\mathrm{Gamma}(k=e, \text{ scale})$ or by $\mathrm{NB}(r=e,\ p)$ very robustly. That makes me wonder if there is something special about this process and this particular value of the shape parameter might hint to that.

Comment: The reason I'm asking is that one of the variables in my computer simulations can be fitted by $Gamma(k=e, scale)$ or by $NB(r=e, p) very robustly. That makes me wonder if there is something special about this process and this particular value of the shape parameter might hint to that.

Comment: No. The gamma varies smoothly around $k=e$. Even if the formula collapsed to something very simple, and it doesn't, that wouldn't be a reason why it should work particularly well with data. Sometimes numbers just are close to $e$, but without meaning anything. I'd guess the same story for negative binomial.